# How to get OMElement by name in mediate?

Tags: class, wso2

I have a response message like this:

```
<message>
    <header>
        <TransactionID>1</TransactionID>
        <Timestamp>2012-05-22 10:10:36</Timestamp>
        <OpCode>BOSS_DELETE_USER_SME.CD</OpCode>
        <MsgType>RESP</MsgType>
        <ReturnCode>1016</ReturnCode>
        <ErrorMessage>uif return error message!</ErrorMessage>
    </header>
</message>
```

I need convert RetuenCode "1016" to "0" in extension class.  How to get OMElement "ReturnCode" in mediate? My code is failed.

```
SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getEnvelope();
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
QName ReturnCode = new QName(null, "ReturnCode");       
OMElement response = soapBody.getFirstChildWithName(ReturnCode);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section

```
<header>
```

Is it inside the SOAP body ? if that is the case first you need to get the Header element from SOAP body and then get the first child with name ReturnCode from that element.

cheers,
Charith

Comment: Yes, it in the SOAP body. But how to get element "ReturnCode". I want get it by name, but failed. How to get a element by name in media? Could you help me? Thank you very much.